# Can i build C# projects on Ubuntu with Jenkins?

Tags: c#, .net, linux, jenkins

We have `Jenkins` running on an `Ubuntu OS 18.04.01 LTS` and an older project written in `C#` / `.NET 4.5`

The application was always build manually in the past and I would like to use Jenkins to introduce `CI` so nobody needs to build the project manually anymore. The application does not have to run on `Linux` or anything like that, we just need the buildfiles (executables and DLL files). Is it possible to build this `C#` solution with `Jenkins` on `Ubuntu`?

I know about `MONO` and `XBUILD` but actually I can't manage to build the project under ubuntu because of different issues which do not happen under `Windows`, e.g. see here:

```
 UserControls/ExpandablePanel.cs(33,35): error CS1043: Invalid accessor body `=>', expecting `;' or `{'
    UserControls/ExpandablePanel.cs(33,66): error CS1043: Invalid accessor body `=>', expecting `;' or `{'
    UserControls/ExpandablePanel.cs(35,41): error CS1043: Invalid accessor body `=>', expecting `;' or `{'
    UserControls/ExpandablePanel.cs(37,40): error CS1043: Invalid accessor body `=>', expecting `;' or `{'
    UserControls/ExpandablePanel.cs(133,22): error CS1644: Feature `pattern matching' cannot be used because it is not part of the C# 6.0 language specification
    UserControls/PagedDataGridView.cs(441,68): error CS1043: Invalid accessor body `=>', expecting `;' or `{'

     1 Warning(s)
     6 Error(s)
```

Is it even possible or do I definitely need to run `Jenkins` on a `Windows` machine?

Comment: You need to specify C# version 7 in your .csproj for these errors to go away.
This article might help you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible. You can build C# project on Linux/Ubuntu. Try building using `mono`. When you will install `mono` package, one of the binaries that you will get will be `xbuild`. To build just invoke the following command:

`xbuild <path to csproj/solution file>`

Try building this manually first and then integrate with jenkins.

Comment: I tried this as stated above but can't manage to build the project with xbuild. Are there any constraints?

Comment: You are using an advanced C# feature (I think it is C# 7 feature). Use the latest mono version. What is the mono version you are using?

Comment: I just made a second jenkins worker based on Windows to avoid any other conflict - it just seemed easier. Nevertheless I accepted your answer because xbuild/mono is the only way to build a C# project on Linux.